# apache mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need some help with a rewrite please.

I have domain `http://www.example.com`. There are multiple folders within the root. I'd like to rewrite `http://www.example.com/folder1/public/index.php` to `http://www.example.com/folder1`

I dont have access to the main apache config so i'll need to do this in a `.htaccess`. If possible I'd also like to place the `.htaccess` inside `folder1`, not in the root.

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking monkey is close.  Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1

RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

You need the `RewriteBase`and you need to stop recursive evaluation of the rule.  The `(?!public/)` bit just means don't match anything already starting with `public/`.  You need this sort of guard in .htaccess rules.

Comment: Should the RewriteBase be `/folder1`?

Comment: @Ulrich, thanks for this correction. -- `/foo` was the directory on my test VM where I validated this solutions :oops:  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to redirect any request to `folder1` to `folder1/public`.
By that I mean, you want your URLs to look like `http://www.example.com/folder1` while the actual URL will be `http://www.example.com/folder1/public/index.php`.

First of all, you have to use `http://www.example.com/folder1` in your hrefs and rewrite this to `http://www.example.com/folder1/public/index.php`.

Add the below to your `.htaccess` residing in your folder `folder1`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: not getting any errors, seems as though the rule isnt working. i can still only access the public folder by adding it in the url

Comment: @agh does your shared hosting allow mod_rewrite (`.htaccess`)?